# New Transaction not allowed error in a web method that uses database transactions

Tags: database, service, web, concurrency, transactions

I am writing a **WCF** service method to Update two tables (header and Details). I need to be sure that the operation is atomic, So I started a transaction surrounding the inserts.

However since this is a web service method, other users could call the same function as this transaction is being used.

One extra information, I am using a custom **ORM** kind of framework that stores connection in the session for re-use.

When the second Web method call comes in, I am getting the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): New transaction is not allowed because 
>   there are other threads running in the session.

I understand that it is because the transaction started by the first call is not completed yet.

I want to understand what are the best practices for using database transaction in a web service and also if I can remedy this situation without have to create a new connection every time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sounds like the other method call is trying to use the same connection as the first one, while it is not released properly.

You usually have a connection pool and you take connections from it from a wcf request and you return it to the pool (by calling Close() or Dispose() or something similar - depends on you orm) after you are done with the database, before the end of the web service call:

-> Wcf method -> Start transaction -> get connection from the pool -> do work -> close connection (return to the pool) -> commit transaction -> return ->

Using session to store the connection might not be a good idea as connection object cannot be really shared between threads.